# Rails 4 - Feedzirra NoMethodError - undefined method `updated?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, feedzirra

I'm trying to check a feed for updates using `Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)` with the feedzirra gem but I keep getting "NoMethodError - undefined method `updated?' for nil:NilClass". The feed I'm fetching from doesn't have etag properties, but it does have last_modified info which I understand needs to be used for the update function to work, but I still can't figure out where I'm going wrong

```
def self.update_from_feed

    feed_url = ENV['FEED_URL']
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
    last_modified = feed.last_modified
end

def self.update_from_feed_continuously

  updated_feed = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)
  add_entries(updated_feed.new_entries) if updated_feed.updated?

end
```

Comment: Where is `feed` defined when used in `Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)`?

Comment: @cortex I was trying to use the feed in the `update_from_feed` method above, (guess I should have used @feed ?) but even though that can't work I've also tried putting the exact same `feed` variable in the `update_from_feed_continuously` method and I still get the same undefined method error

Comment: Does `update_from_feed` method work?

Comment: @cortex yes the update_from_feed method works fine